# Safe Indexing Inside Unsafe Code

Tags: c#, unsafe, stackalloc

Good morning, afternoon or night,

**Foreword:** The code below does nothing really useful. It is just for explanation purposes.

Is there anything wrong with allocating and using an array "the safe mode" inside unsafe code? For example, should I write my code as

```
public static unsafe uint[] Test (uint[] firstParam, uint[] secondParam)
{
    fixed (uint * first = firstParam, second = secondParam)
    {
        uint[] Result = new uint[firstParam.Length + secondParam.Length];

        for (int IndTmp = 0; IndTmp < firstParam.Length; Result[IndTmp] = *(first + IndTmp++));
        for (int IndTmp = 0; IndTmp < secondParam.Length; Result[IndTmp + firstParam.Length] = *(second + IndTmp++);

        return Result;
    }
}
```

or should I instead write a separate, unsafe method accepting only pointers and lengths as parameters and use it in the main function?

Also, is there any way I can replace the allocation with

```
uint * Result = stackalloc uint[firstParam.Length + secondParam.Length]
```

so that I can use `Result` as a pointer and still be able to return `Result` as an `uint[]`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with doing that, although if you're using pointers for speed, it probably makes sense to use a pointer into `Result` also. Maybe like this:

```
public static unsafe uint[] Test (uint[] firstParam, uint[] secondParam)
{
    uint[] Result = new uint[firstParam.Length + secondParam.Length];
    fixed (uint * first = firstParam, second = secondParam, res = Result)
    {
        for (int IndTmp = 0; IndTmp < firstParam.Length; IndTmp++)
            *(res + IndTmp) = *(first + IndTmp);
        res += firstParam.Length;
        for (int IndTmp = 0; IndTmp < secondParam.Length; IndTmp++)
            *(res + IndTmp) = *(second + IndTmp++);
    }
    return Result;
}
```

**DO NOT** return anything you `stackalloc`! Once the function returns, the area allocated on the stack is reused, giving you an invalid pointer.